# Show colors in checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I am new on this site, and i am danish, so my english is not the best.

I wanna make a page where you can edit a product, so i have made a lot of textboxe's and it shows all of the "specs" the product have, i have made that width Whlile reader.reads. But the product have a variable number of colors that i also have to show via a checkboxlist. So if you want to add more color you can check other colors to.

I have an product table with some products on, and a color table with some colors on. Then i have an table with product id and color id combined, so every product can have 0 - 10 color (cause that is how many colors there is).

Then i want to show how many colors one pruduct have. I have selected product id by querystring but how do i show it in a checkboxlist?

I tried this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FarveTilCykel WHERE fk_cy_id = @id";

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    if (conn != null)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

and this

```
foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FarveTilCykel WHERE fk_cy_id = @id";
    SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Open();
    string CheckId = item.Value.ToString();
    if (conn.DataSource.Contains(CheckId))
    {
        item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

MY checkbox list:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="farve_navn" DataValueField="farve_id"></asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Farver]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add items to your checkboxlist?

Comment: Yeah, but i forgot to say that i have selected the table with colors in the checkboxlist's datasource with name showed and id as value :) I just have to make the colors that the product have, be checked :)

Comment: No, i dont think so :)

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand the situation. Is the CheckBoxList empty and you want to fill it with the colors names loaded from the datatable?

Comment: No, i have fllled it with names and values, but i want to show witch color the product have by checking the particular color in the checkboxlist.

Comment: But wait, how do you check if a particular value(for example a number) is in a table?

Comment: I have added some more explaination in the question :)

Comment: How do you fill the CheckBoxList? Are you setting its DataSource to some kind of query and sets its DisplayMember and ValueMember properties?

Comment: I have filled it with DisplayMember (color name) and ValueMember (color id) by DataSource

Comment: Looks like you are using  ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: sorry :( i tagged c#